# Реализация функции last

Tags: функции, рекурсия, haskell, функциональное-программирование

Мною была написана реализация функции last, с помощью рекурсии:

```
last' :: [a] -> a
last' []  = error "empty list"
last' [x] = x
last' (_:xs) = last' xs
```

Как работает рекурсия в данном случае?

Возможна ли реализация данной функции, без использования рекурсии?

Comment: В прелюде реализовано, по сути, так же. А как работает рекурсия... Вы на каждом шаге рекурсии вызываете свою функцию с аргументом на один элемент короче. В конце концов, у Вас в списке останется один элемент, который будет возвращен в качестве результата очередного вызова, и по всем шагам рекурсии поднимется назад к точке ее начала.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Рекурсия в данном случае работает так: на третьей строчке (которая `(_:xs)`) функция вызывает сама себя, передавая хвост списка в качестве параметра, и это происходит до тех пор, пока в хвосте не остаётся ровно один элемент, и в этот момент срабатывает вторая строчка (которая `[x]`), которая и возвращает результат.

Без рекурсии подобный алгоритм реализовать нельзя, поскольку в языке Haskell не существует циклов типа `for` или `while`, которые есть в других языках. Единственный способ "повторить много раз" в Haskell - это рекурсия.

Вы можете реализовать эту функцию без *явной* рекурсии - т.е. не используя рекурсию в вашем собственном коде, - с помощью библиотечных функций, например `foldr1`:

```
last xs = foldr1 (\_ x -> x) xs
```

Но и в этом случая рекурсия там всё равно будет, просто она будет спрятана внутри `foldr1`.